# Double iterating through a Hash Map in Java

Tags: java

I used the following way to join the sets generated in apriori join step

```
Iterator<Entry<List<Integer>, Integer>> i1 = hm.entrySet().iterator() ;
Iterator<Entry<List<Integer>, Integer>> i2 = hm.entrySet().iterator() ;

while(i1.hasNext()) {
    while(i2.hasNext()) {

        Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> pair1 = i1.next() ; 
        Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> pair2 = i2.next() ; 

        // Do some joining part here

        System.out.println(pair1.getKey());
        System.out.println(pair2.getKey());

        } 
    }
}
```

Actually, I thought that it will iterate through all the n*n values of the hash map. But what is happening is that both of the iterators are executing in parallel and executing only n times as if both the iterators are same. Please suggest a way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the second Iterator inside the outer loop, in order for it to restart iterating over the entries before each iteration of the inner loop.

Another required change is to obtain the current entry of the first iterator outside the inner loop.

```
Iterator<Entry<List<Integer>, Integer>> i1 = hm.entrySet().iterator() ; 
while(i1.hasNext()) {
    Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> pair1 = i1.next() ; 
    Iterator<Entry<List<Integer>, Integer>> i2 = hm.entrySet().iterator() ;
    while(i2.hasNext()) {
        Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> pair2 = i2.next() ; 
        // Do some joining part here

        System.out.println(pair1.getKey());
        System.out.println(pair2.getKey());
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: And you could do away with the explicit Iterator and use a `for` loop on `entrySet`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<List<Integer>, Integer> hm.....;

for (Map.Entry<List<Integer>,Integer> pair1 : hm.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<List<Integer>,Integer> pair2 : hm.entrySet()) {
        // do anything you want with pair1 and pair2,
        // just don't make structural change to hm
    }
}
```

Doesn't see much value of explicit iterator usage here, and I think it is so much clearer to simply use for-each loop (aka enhanced for loop), so I slightly change OP's approach.

Comment: aaaah no idea why i made such kind of obvious mistakes.  thanks for pointing out